# How to get the function keys on an HP Pavilion keyboard to act as function keys instead of controls for sound, brightness and such

Tags: keyboard

On my laptop—HP Pavilion running Arch Linux—all the function keys of my keyboard are set to action by default (like sound, brightness, plane mode...). If I want to use <kbd>F1</kbd> I have to use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Is it possible to switch this behavior and put <kbd>F*</kbd> as default and use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to use the actions?

Comment: This is normally configurable in the BIOS.

Comment: @DavidPostill Awesome it worked! Thanks!